# How to split List into segments

Tags: list, scala

Suppose I need to split a given list into segments of 3 like this:

```
val l = (0 until 5).toList
val segments = l.tails.map(_.take(3)).filter(_.size == 3).toList
segments: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))
```

I got the `segments` I need but the code is obviously ugly. How would you rewrite it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]):

```
val segments: Iterator[List[Int]] = l.sliding(3)

segments.toList
> List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))
```